# python requesting clarification on TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, set, typeerror

need some clarification on the error im facing.

The corpus is a Python dictionary mapping a page name to a set of all pages linked to by that page.

The page is a string representing the page

when i try this  `linkouts = corpus[page]`

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

when i print `corpus[page]` this is the output (corpus is a dict of sets)
`{'3.html', '1.html'}`
when i ```print(type(corpus[page])) the output is set.

I am able to iterate through `corpus[page]` , but if i attempt to `len(corpus[page])` the same error occurs. is `corpus[page]` not a set? How should I go around this error? Makinf a `corpus[page].copy()` also faces the same issue. Would appreciate any advice and help, thank you people!

code for pagelink.py

```
import os
import random
import re
import sys

DAMPING = 0.85
SAMPLES = 10000


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("Usage: python pagerank.py corpus")
    corpus = crawl(sys.argv[1])
    ranks = sample_pagerank(corpus, DAMPING, SAMPLES)
    print(f"PageRank Results from Sampling (n = {SAMPLES})")
    for page in sorted(ranks):
        print(f"  {page}: {ranks[page]:.4f}")
    #ranks = iterate_pagerank(corpus, DAMPING)
    #print(f"PageRank Results from Iteration")
    for page in sorted(ranks):
        print(f"  {page}: {ranks[page]:.4f}")


def crawl(directory):
    """
    Parse a directory of HTML pages and check for links to other pages.
    Return a dictionary where each key is a page, and values are
    a list of all other pages in the corpus that are linked to by the page.
    """
    pages = dict()

    # Extract all links from HTML files
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if not filename.endswith(".html"):
            continue
        with open(os.path.join(directory, filename)) as f:
            contents = f.read()
            links = re.findall(r"<a\s+(?:[^>]*?)href=\"([^\"]*)\"", contents)
            pages[filename] = set(links) - {filename}

    # Only include links to other pages in the corpus
    for filename in pages:
        pages[filename] = set(
            link for link in pages[filename]
            if link in pages
        )

    return pages


def transition_model(corpus, page, damping_factor):
    """
    Return a probability distribution over which page to visit next,
    given a current page.

    With probability `damping_factor`, choose a link at random
    linked to by `page`. With probability `1 - damping_factor`, choose
    a link at random chosen from all pages in the corpus.
    """
    linkouts =  set(corpus[page])
    output = {}
    for key in corpus:
        output[key] = 0.00
    dampvalue = damping_factor / len(linkouts)
    for link in linkouts:
        output[link] += dampvalue
    if linkouts:
        dampvalue = 1 - damping_factor
        dampvalue = dampvalue / len(corpus)
        for key in corpus:
            output[key] += dampvalue
    else:
        dampvalue = 1 / len(corpus)
        for key in corpus:
            output[key] += dampvalue
    return output



def sample_pagerank(corpus, damping_factor, n):
    """
    Return PageRank values for each page by sampling `n` pages
    according to transition model, starting with a page at random.

    Return a dictionary where keys are page names, and values are
    their estimated PageRank value (a value between 0 and 1). All
    PageRank values should sum to 1.
    """
    samples = []
    first = random.choice(list(corpus))
    samples.append(first)
    for i in range(n-1):
        output = transition_model(corpus, first, damping_factor)
        second = random.choices(list(output), weights=(output.values()))
        samples.append(second)
        first = second

    output = {}
    for link in corpus:
        num = 0
        for sample in samples:
            if sample == link:
                num += 1
        output[link] = num / n

    return output





def iterate_pagerank(corpus, damping_factor):
    """
    Return PageRank values for each page by iteratively updating
    PageRank values until convergence.

    Return a dictionary where keys are page names, and values are
    their estimated PageRank value (a value between 0 and 1). All
    PageRank values should sum to 1.
    """
    raise NotImplementedError


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

code for `1.html` and `2.html` in a folder(corpus0) in same folder wwith pagerank.py

1.html

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>1</h1>

        <div>Links:</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="2.html">2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>2</h1>

        <div>Links:</div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="1.html">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="3.html">3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Program is ran with python pagerank.py corpus0

EDIT

```
linkouts = []
    for i in corpus[page]:
        linkouts.append(i)
```

gives the same type error but if i replace `linkouts.append(i)` with `print(i)` theres no error, also `i` is type `str`

Comment: It depends on the type of `page`. I think you might be using different page objects to index and getting different results. Consider posting a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get better feedback.

Comment: @nneonneo yep added. but ```page``` is a string

Comment: The problem seemsd to be with ```sample_pagerank``` and not ```transition_model```

Answer (score 0):

`random.choices`  returns a list even when `k=1`, hence for the 2nd iteration onwards i was sending a `list` to `transition_model`  in `pages`

inside `sample_pagerank` fixed by

```
for i in range(n-1):
        output = transition_model(corpus, first, damping_factor)
        second = random.choices(list(output), weights=(output.values()), k=1)[0]
        samples.append(second)
        first = second
```